# regex in a string (until space)

Tags: regex

I have the following snippet

```
cv_13221 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
```

and just want to get cv_13221 out of it.

I tried the following regex

```
cv_.*\s
```

but it fetches me

```
cv_13221 IN OUT
```

what can I do to make it stop at first occurrence of \s

I am trying this in regex buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reluctant Kleene closure instead of a greedy one. Usually this is the syntax for it:

```
cv_.*?\s
```

Usually, the Kleene closure operator (`*`) will match as much as possible. The reluctant Kleene closure operator (`*?`) matches as little as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
cv_\S+
```

The capital 'S' in '\S' means: match a non-space character. And the + means one or nore, of course.
Or:

```
cv_\d+
```

when it's always digits that come after the underscore: best to be as specific as you can when dealing with regex.

Comment: +1 for providing the better alternative of being more specific in the regex. I personally avoid using .* myself where possible, unless I specifically want an entire line or whatnot.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: couldn't agree more!

Answer (score 2):

.* is greedy.  it will grab as much as it can before upto the last space.  try this:

```
cv_[^\s]*
```